# Give a "non-user" account access to ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, permissions, users

I'm running a python application (a monitor) called *Tautulli*.

This application are running under the user tautulli.

Now, the app is performing different functions depending on other stuff.

The thing I'm having an issue with is that I need it to execute another script on a remote server via ssh, **BUT** it appears that the user "*tautulli*" don't have permission to do this, because I'm getting this error message:

> Could not create directory '/home/tautulli/.ssh

So I'm guessing this has something to do with user access, but have no idea how to solve it..
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the `tautulli` user not have write permissions in its own home directory?

Comment: It's also possible that the user was created *without* a home directory. So I would make sure the home directory exists for that user. You can check for example the entry for that user in /etc/passwd. Or just run `echo $HOME` from the command line as user tautulli. It the directory exists, look at the permissions for example with `ls -lh`.

Answer (score 0):

Tautulli hadn't created a physical home-directory, even thou it was specified in the /etc/passwd file.

Upon creating and using `chown tautulli:tautulli tautulli` it now have full access.

Comment: This was a typical newbie mistake, to assuming that an account that was created by an application, was correctly created..

Comment: On Centos `useradd user` automatically creates its home directory but it doesn't on Ubuntu.